# Apple HTML5 progressive streaming

Tags: ipad, video

Is there a copy of the file saved to the ipad/ipod when using progressive http download (apple segmented) that the user could potentially copy off the device?

meaning, is this scenario considered 'safe' from a content protection pov:
1. user comes to websites with movies behind paywall
2. user selects a movie to watch online (progressively downloaded or 'pseudo-streamed')
3. segments are downloaded seamlessly by html5 video tag as part of .m3u8
4. movie plays/ends.

is there any full copy of this movie on the device that can be transferred off? anyone know apple's stance on this?

Comment: Even if Safari automatically deletes movies as users watch them (I doubt it), I can pretty much guarantee someone has or will write a Firefox addon to save these kinds of movies.

Comment: brendan, very true. i should have clarified that i think we're talking about ONLY apple devices, i.e  not serve to firefox user agent.

Answer (score 2):

I'd worry less about people obtaining the files from some hidden-away cache, and more about the fact you've got an http URL which allows the file to be directly downloaded onto *any* device.

You can dance around this and check for user-agent strings, session cookies etc, but there's not much you can do prevent someone from figuring it out, and writing an easy way around it.

Comment: ok. now, lets say we're at a low-enough resolution where the people who go to steal movies dont care about your 360 or  480p master and go easily rip from DVDs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can segment using mediafilesegmenter in such a way that the files can only be viewed from the online location. I could be wrong about that, but if you check out the mediafilesegmenter docs, there appears to be many security options. That's where I'd look.